# Unity Greeter login screen cuts off login options

Tags: 12.04, login, display, resolution, unity-greeter

I have a pretty newly installed Ubuntu 12.04, using Unity. My external monitor is 1920x1080 max resolution. In the Unity desktop itself everything looks great. I have an NVidia graphics card.

When I start my computer and get to the Unity greeter login screen the display is oddly formatted and the resolution seems off. It looks like a zoomed view on the larger 1920x1080 screen. As such it crops the login options off to the left hand side of the screen. So I can only just see the edge of the password box for the user I want to log in with.

I can log in with one account by default by blindly typing the password, but I am unable to switch to other accounts.

Is there anything I can do to fix the log in screen display so that I can see the normal login options?

Note: I first noticed it when I changed my desktop background and the next time I logged in I saw the issue.

Comment: Have you installed the proprietary drivers?

Comment: Yes. I had problems before where the entire display wasn't working until I installed the correct version of NVidia display drivers.

Comment: To clarify I have NVidia Driver version 173.14.35. I had problems using the (version current)[Recommended] not working on my monitor at all. Is there anyway that the unity-greeter might not be using the right driver version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this through (re-)installing the NVidia current-updates driver version.

Go to System Settings > Available Drivers

I selected NVidia accelerated graphics driver (post-release updates) (version current-updates) and clicked Activate.

After downloading and installing I had to restart everything worked fine.

Comment: FYI, I previously had version 173 drivers. My graphics card is reported as GeForce 6150SE nForce 430/integrated/SSE2.